# How to trigger axios request from input length of 3 in React useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I was wondering how to trigger my axios requests from a search input only when it has at least a length of 3.

I'm in a React project and uses hooks. The axios is in a useEffect function, the input is in a state.

I've tried to put input.length > 3 in the dependency array and it trigger well but only once... If i've got a fourth letter, it doesn't trigger the request.

I don't want to use the cancel request :)

The handlecChange function :

```
const handleInputChange = event => {
    setPage(1)
    setListeMediasFiltree([])
    setfilters({...filters, libelle: event.target.value})
  }
```

Here is the useEffect function :

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Si le media est relié à un élément (passé en props)
    if (relatedElement) {
      if (relatedElement.id) {
        getAllMedias(relatedElement, relatedType)
          .then(data => {
            setListeMedias(data);
          })
      } else {
        setListeMedias([]);
      }
    } else {
      if (hasMore) {
        if (filters.libelle.length >= 3 || filters.format.length > 0 || filters.objet.length > 0 || filters.extension.length > 0) {
          // Fonction appelée s'il n'y a pas de related element et a chaque filtre ajouté
          getMedias(page, options.size, filters)
            .then(data => {
              setListeMedias([])
              setListeMediasFiltree([...listeMediasFiltree, ...data.data]);
              setTotalPage(data.last_page)
              setIsFetching(false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              errorSnackbar('Un problème est survenu lors de la requete avec filtre')
              console.error(error)
            })
        } else {
          // Fonction appelée lorsqu'il n'y a pas de related element et aucun filtre
          getMedias(page, options.size)
            .then(data => {
              setListeMedias([...listeMedias, ...data.data]);
              setTotalPage(data.last_page)
              setIsFetching(false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              errorSnackbar('Un problème est survenu lors du chargement des médias')
              console.error(error)
            })
        }
      }
    }
  }, [refreshList, page, filters.libelle.length >= 3, filters.format, filters.objet, filters.extension]);
```

Comment: Did you try calling `getMedias` inside `handleInputChange` ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but I'm not sure if it's the right way as the dependency array is here for something. Another way would be to trigger when the user stop typing... any idea? cheers

Comment: I've workaround the problem and started to use debounce from Lodash library and it work very well ! 

Thanks